# R: importing data from a CSV, the separators is "\"" but get error more columns than column names

Tags: r, csv

I having a problem separating a csv file that interprets mutiple row inputs as:

```
[1] "bizname,addr,bizphone,numrevs"                "Jersey Smoke,\""
[3] "            84 N Main St, Milltown, NJ 08850" "        \",\""
[5] "        (732) 253-7977"                       "    \",\""
```

The first string is the headers within the file. Now the problem is that there is additional quotation marks within the data, and if I try to split the data based on the quotation marks using something like this:

```
vapeshopsnj1 <- read.csv("~/Desktop/newjerseyvapeshopsA.csv", 
    row.names = NULL, sep="\"", header = TRUE, 
    colClasses= "character", encoding= "utf-8")
```

There is an error that is produced which is:

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,: more columns than column names

Comment: @RaphaelK I am unsure if that works, but I know the below works. Thank you very much for your response though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two hours of google-ing and reading various stack-exchange posts, and R resources I have found the answer. If this saves you two hours one day, you can thank this post:

```
vapeshopsnj1 <- read.csv("~/Desktop/newjerseyvapeshopsA.csv", row.names = NULL, quote = "\"", header = TRUE, colClasses= "character", encoding= "utf-8")
```

Comment: I guess you should provide a glimpse of your file, if you want your answer to be helpful to anybody. It's not clear what the sample you provided in the question represents. I suspect that you have the single-quote (`'`) somewhere in your data and that produced the error.